# ASP.NET MVC Async Action doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have an issue with this simple async code. The execution goes througth the TestAsync action and goes througth the delay method but when the delay method returns nothing else happens.
it seems like blocked for some reason.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAsync()
{
     try
     {
         var res = await doLongOperation();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     catch (Exception e) { }
 }

 private Task<bool> doLongOperation()
 {
     var test = new Task<bool>(() => { /*do the long operation..*/ return true; });
     return test;
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`new Task<bool>(() => true)` returns a task that is not started yet. This is an old syntax that requires you to invoke the [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the task. If you don't invoke the `Start` method, the task will never complete, and thus asynchronous execution will never continue (`await` will asynchronously wait forever).

If you simply want to delay execution, then simply use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
private async Task<bool> delay()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    return true;
}
```

In general, it is always recommended to create tasks that are already started upon creation.

If you want to create a task that runs on a thread-pool thread, then use the [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: I don't want to delay,  it should be a DoSomething task. So, how can I start the task on creation.?

Comment: I would discourage us from leading someone on to think that using Task.Run() in an asp.net application would be a viable solution, as that's really just killing the scalability of their application since it needlessly takes up another thread pool thread on something that is actually a synchronous action. @DevT, I encourage you to just spend time studying the async/await pattern so you can get a strong basis on what Async is/isn't.

Comment: @DevT, what would the `DoSomething` task do and why would you want to make it asynchronous? does it involve any IO?

Comment: @DavidY, I mentioned `Task.Run` at the end just to make my answer complete. It is not clear from the question what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I understand, I just do not want OP to do that and crater his application, as the title does specifically give it an ASP.NET context. I certainly understand why you put Task.Run() as an example, I just wanted to make sure OP had an opportunity to see it would not be a good thing to do in a web context.

Comment: It is just an example... The task should do a generic "long" operation

Comment: If I use var res = await Task.Run(delay) it doesn't work

Comment: @DavidY Thanks for the suggestion, as for the updated post, my task has to do a long operation and I just want the thread that started a long-running operation is released to do other things.

Comment: @DevT, why do you want to do a long running operation during an ASP.NET request? Do you want to caller to wait while the long operation is running?

Comment: @DevT I understand what you want to do, however I don't believe you are going to the results you are expecting with async/await. I believe the article I posted in my answer is going to help you understand what async really is and how it is helpful in a web context. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'm studying asynchronous programming, and I learned that the main characteristic of asynchronous code is that the thread that started a long-running operation is released to do other things. So we can suppose that the my long operation is a complex query on a database

Comment: @DevT in the exact scenario you mentioned you would await the async method call to execute that query on the database. Many database API's now have an Async version of their synchronous call to the database that you can await directly. This would be the perfect use of async/await. Your request thread would be free while the database server is doing work executing your query, and then resume when it finished.

Comment: @DavidY yes I agree, but if I have a database that doesn't expose async API ? I can't do nothing to release the thread ?

Comment: @DevT You could release the current thread, but basically your only other option is to then take up another thread from the thread pool on your web server, essentially taking up more resources to do something you only have synchronous actions to use. Say you wrap up your sync database call in Task.Run(), your current request thread would get freed, but then another one would be taken from your webserver to execute the task created by the .Run() call.

Comment: @DavidY oh right, I don't know why I didn't think of this before. 
You 've opened my eyes

Answer (score 0):

The method posted in your question doesn't work properly because the task is not started, there's nothing finishing so your await is waiting indefinitely. If you want to use Async it's best to use async all the way down, especially in an ASP.NET context. If you are not doing anything that is truly asynchronous, then in a web development context, just allow it to be synchronous.

I honestly believe the most good that will be done here is for you to spend time studying async/await, an excellent resource is found here: [Stephen Cleary Blog on Async](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)